# How to hidden the sub NSView according to the window size in Mac OS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, nsstackview

I am coding an MacOS app with swift. The main layout in the window is like follows:

[image: The layout of the app]

The NSStackView has a sideBar (NSTableView) and a NSView. What I want to achieve is listed here:

1. The width of the sideBar is fixed when changing the window size.
2. When the width of the window is smaller than `WIDTH_THRESHOLD`, the sideBar is hidden.

The **problems** are

1. For Target 1, the constraints of the sideBar and the NSView is like follows, but it doesn't work and the width of the sideBar still changes.

[image: The constraints]

2. For Target 2, the project has a `NSWindowController` and a `NSViewController`. I can listen the window size in `NSWindowController`, but I don't know how to transport this msg to the `NSViewController` to hidden the sideBar.

Notice that NSStackView has the properties like `Hugging Priority`, `Clipping Resistance Priority` and `Visibility Priorities` in size inspector, can I achieve the targets through setting these properties (in the following figure)?

[image: The properties]

Comment: I think an NSSplitView or NSSplitViewController would be more appropriate for a sidebar application than NSStackView would be.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you constrained the width of the sidebar? If you haven't, what may be happening is that the `NSView` is autoresizing and pushing the sidebar around. Changing the red arrows doesn't create actual constraints, just changes the resizing rules.
2. Listen to the window size in your `NSWindowController`, just like you said. As long as you have a reference to your side bar available in that window class (e.g. you can access the view controller that contains it), you can set `sideBar.isHidden = true` when the window gets too small, and `false` when the window is large enough again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Finally, I use NSSplitView as the sideBar and it is much easier.
2. I use `NSSplitViewDelegate` to listen the width change of the SplitView.